# How do you change video format to mp4 in MediaRecorder()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I followed fireship's tutorial on making a video recorder app using electronjs. When using the MediaRecorder function to record a video of the screen you pass in an option to specify the video format which is in this case video/webm. I want to change it to video/mp4 but I don't know what to put there. At the moment it looks like this:

```
const options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
const media = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

I read the MDN documentation on this but I don't know anything about video formats. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter.
I tried to pass in "video/mp4; codecs=avc1.4d002a" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all browsers support MP4 encoding or playback. One example is Chromium, which Chrome, Brave, Edge, and others are based on.

Simply setting `mimeType` of `MediaRecorder` won't work.

To find out if the `MediaRecorder` implementation in the browser you are using support MP4 recording you can run

```
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("video/mp4")
```

There are several third-party libraries you can use to encode media to MP4, such as https://github.com/Vanilagy/mp4-muxer, and https://github.com/vjeux/mp4-h264-re-encode.